# Doxygen alias similar to \see or \sa

Tags: c++, doxygen

I would like to define an alias that behaves similar to `\sa` or `\see`, e.g. groups subsequent paragraphs marked with it into one section and lists each item on a single line.

e.g.

```
\foo One
\foo Two
\foo Three
```

Should end up as

```
Foo:
  One
  Two
  Three
```

Long story short: An alias that behaves like `\see` but has a different label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [`\xrefitem`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdxrefitem) command. From the doxygen documentation (emphasis mine):

> This command is a generalization of commands such as `\todo` and `\bug`. It can be used to create user-defined text sections which are automatically cross-referenced between the place of occurrence and a related page, which will be generated. **On the related page all sections of the same type will be collected.**

The example in the documentation suggests that you place the alias

```
ALIASES += "reminder=\xrefitem reminders \"Reminder\" \"Reminders\""
```

in your configuration file. Then writing something like

```
\reminder test 1
\reminder test 2
\reminder test 3
```

in your documentation will result in something like:

```
Reminder:  
   test 1  
   test 2  
   test 3
```

The only problem with this is that you will under an additional page under the "Related pages" tab called "Reminders". If you don't want this related page you can use an alias as documented in the [custom commands](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/custcmd.html) documentation:

```
ALIASES += sideeffect="\par Side Effects:\n"
```

which will allow you to put the command `\sideeffect` in the documentation, which will result in a user-defined paragraph with a heading **Side Effects:**. However, these will not be grouped together in the final documentation (i.e. each `\sideeffect` will generate a **Side Effects:** heading).

Comment: You could also construct your own list using [`\li](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/commands.html#cmdli) and place a header just before the list. The header (and the list) can be HTML.

Comment: Thanks. Those are exactly the same solutions I came up with but I was hoping for something that doesn't come with a down-side. The best would be `xrefitem` without the related page.

Comment: I ran into some problems with this. If you define an alias this way, and use it with `\reminder 'SomeClass'` (imagine the ' to be a backtick) to link it, linking does not happen. This works with `\sa`. But this seems to be a doxygen bug.